# How redux works with a simple example (irrespective of react)?

Tags: redux

I have seen a lot of redux examples and know that its for state management but the more I read the more confusing it becomes. can someone simply put redux example for understanding purpose to demonstrate how it works?

Comment: You can improve your question by posting an specific example of what you mean by work. Redux does a lot of things, so first you need to try to understrand **what** it does in order to ask **how** does the job. Of course understanding what does may be difficul as well leading to other questions that you can ask in SO.

Comment: I suggest you to watch the tutorials on egghead.io, try to build something, and then make questions more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned you have gone through redux and know whats its made for let me demonstrate it to you with a very simple example with isolation without any framework.

**Simplest Example (I thought of)**

```
const {createStore} = require('redux');

const initialState = {
    name : "faisal"
}
const mReducer = (state = initialState,action)=>{
    const newState = {...state};
    if(action.type==="QAIS"){
        newState.name = "Qais";
    }

    if(action.type==="AZHAR"){
        newState.name = "Azhar";
    }
    return newState;
};

const mSubscriber = ()=>{
    console.log("Name : "+store.getState().name);
}

const store = createStore(mReducer);
store.subscribe(mSubscriber);
store.dispatch({type:"QAIS"});
store.dispatch({type:"AZHAR"});
store.dispatch({type:"ASAD"});
```

As you can observe from the example a simple store that holds the **Reducer** which is the method responsible for changing in state, with respect to actions it receive.

and a **Subscriber** that listen for state changing.

all we have to do is to createStore with your Reducer and Subscribe to store .its observer pattern where the changes state are being observed. and finally try passing actions by **dispatching** them to store once they are dispatched the Reducer comes into action and modifies the state which is then observed by the Subscriber. :) simple is that.

Answer (score 3):

Top of all, Let's see exactly what is the purpose of using Redux; Redux is something like the 'state' concept in React with **global operation domain**. that's means when we are using redux, we have a single huge state with various child states to use in all of our app's components.

It helps us to reduce the 'props' usage in our app and have easy access to data in other components and a lot of other specs in apps with complex data-flow.

In Redux we have three main concepts: the **store** (providing that main global state), **actions** and **reducers**. every *reducer* is a function which returns an object (depends on what we want using actions) to implement in our *store*.

And *actions* are our handlers (executive arms) to make changes in reducers. in real, actions are the interfaces of reducers to we can make changes in them.

[image]

There is a lot of ways to dispatch actions and using redux in a component. but, as a simple example:

**actions.js:**

```
export var editUserStatus = (status) => {
    return {
        type: 'EDIT_USER_STATUS',
        status: status
    }
}

export var addAUserToUsers = (user) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_A_USER_TO_USERS',
        user: user
    }
}
```

**reducers.js:**

```
export var usersReducer = (state = { status: 'loading'}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'EDIT_USER_STATUS':
            return {
                ...state,
                status: action.status
            }
        case 'ADD_A_USER_TO_USERS':
            return {
                ...state,
                users: state.users.concat(action.user)
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**store.js:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
var thunk = require('redux-thunk').default;    
import {usersReducer} from './usersReducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

var combinedReducers = combineReducers(usersReducer)

export var config = (initialState = {}) => {
    var store = createStore(
        combinedReducers,
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )
    );
    return store;
}
```

And then, as a simple example usage in react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from 'actions'


class myExampleComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.actions.editUserStatus('loaded')
    }

    render() {
        return (<p>{this.props.usersReducer.status}</p>)
    }

}


function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
         usersReducer: state.usersReducer
    }
}

function MapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    MapDispatchToProps
)(myExampleComponent)
```

Comment: but redux is not part of react. keeping it isolated is a great way to look at what it can do instead of learning structure of another framework

Comment: exactly you are right. but the main usage of redux is in React apps and it's easy to understand it via React.

Answer (score 0):

1. When an action is performed in the view section that the user
   encounters when he opens the page or application, the payloads
   (load) of this action are dispatched to the store.
2. In other words, data is transferred to the store thanks to dispatch
   and it now delivers the data to reducers.
3. Actions just tell what the payload data they send will be. They do
   not know how the application will change the data and what to do.
4. At this point, the reducers determine how the application's state
   will change according to the action coming to the store and send it
   to the store.

> In short, reducer does the only job of data exchange and updates the
> store. The store then reflects this update to the view.